# Java EE CDI - producing beans with injected fields

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

Because I have some generics which need to be passed to the newly produced object, I am creating a producer. But while producer works, the `EntityManager` is not injected because producer creates an instance with operator `new` instead of using CDI.

How can I produce an object with CDI support?

The code:

**Qualifier**:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(
{ FIELD, TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface Multiselector
{
   Class<? extends Dbo> clazz();
}
```

**Producer:**

```
@SessionScoped
public class MultiselectorProducer implements Serializable
{

   @Produces
   @Multiselector(clazz = SpecialDbo.class)
   public MultiselectorService<SpecialDbo> produce()
   {
       return  new MultiselectorService<SpecialDbo>(SpecialDbo.class);
   }

}
```

**Service class:**

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class MultiselectorService<T extends Dbo> implements Serializable
{

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    private List<T>     itemList;

    public MultiselectorService()
    {
    }

    public MultiselectorService(Class<? extends Dbo> clazz)
    {
       itemList = em.createQuery("some Sql String", clazz);
    }

    ....
}
```

**NOTE**: The `EntityManager` is a custom crud service which is otherwise injected correctly

Any improvement suggestions over the code are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed a lot of unrelated things:

1. Your service `MultiselectorService` is an EJB, and you cannot produce it with a producer. EJB is registered once application is created and then depending on the scope it creates instances.
2. You have a method `public void MultiselectorService(Class<? extends Dbo> clazz)` with the name similar to constructor, it against convention.
3. Assume that you have fixed that method to be a constructor, but then line 'itemList = em.createQuery("some Sql String", clazz);' will fail with NPE. Because `em` will be initialized only after bean creation. there are two ways to do it:

   - Inject entity manager into constructor (this is against EJB spec, if you will still use EJB)
   - Execute initialization operation in method with annotation '@PostConstruct'
4. Do you have a producer for `EntityManager` ? e.g. you cannot just inject entity manager, you need to provide as a resource for EJB, with annotation `@PersistenceContext`

I understand what you try to achieve. The main problem is that manually created beans are not managed by container, this means that interceptors and decorators won't apply (e.g. PostConstruct and Transactional annotation will not work). Check [here](http://docs.jboss.com/cdi/spec/1.0/html/lifecycle.html). So far the best way to achieve this is:

```
  public interface SpecialDboMultiselectorService extends MultiselectorService {


  }

  @Stateless
  public class SpecialDboMultiselectorServiceImpl extends MultiselectorServiceImpl<SpecialDbo> implements SpecialDboMultiselectorService
  {

        public SpecialDboMultiselectorServiceImpl() {
             super(SpecialDbo.class);
        }
  }


  public class MultiselectorServiceImpl<T extends Dbo> implements MultiselectorService {

     @Inject  
     private EntityManager em;

     private Class<? extends Dbo> clazz;

     private List<T> itemList;

     public MultiselectorService(Class<? extends Dbo> clazz) {
         this.clazz = clazz
     }

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
        itemList = em.createQuery("some Sql String", clazz);
     }
  }
```

and inject `SpecialDboMultiselectorService`.

Comment: The `EntityManager` is a custom crud service which is otherwise injected correctly. On point 3. you are correct, that was a typo. The NPE is exactly my problem, I would much rather use `@PostConstruct`. You did give me some hits for improvements, I'll try them out and report back.

Comment: The produced object does not have transactions and still seems not to be CDI managed, because `@PostConstruct` is never executed.